# Implementing Maybe/Option type in TypeScript using class inheritance

Tags: typescript, class, inheritance, option-type

Most of the Typescript implementations of the Maybe/Option type that I have seen either use an interface with a tag to distinguish between the Some/None variants. I have seen a few that don't and actually have separate classes for Some and None that both implement a common Option interface. As an experiment, I wanted to try an implementation that used inheritance. So here is a simplified version of what I came up with:

```
abstract class Maybe<T> {
    constructor(private value: T) {}

    isSome(): this is Some<T> {
        return this instanceof Some;
    }
  
    isNone(): this is None {
        return !this.isSome();
    }

    and<U>(other: Maybe<U>): Maybe<U> {
        return this.isNone() ? new None() : other;
    }

    unwrap(): T {
        if (this.isNone()) throw new Error('called unwrap() on None');
        return this.value;
    }

    unwrapOr(defaultValue: T): T {
        return this.isNone() ? defaultValue : this.value;
    }
}

class Some<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    constructor(value: T) { super(value); }
}

class None extends Maybe<any> {
    constructor() { super(null); }
}
```

But I'm running into some problems with the type being passed in to `extends Maybe<...>` on the `None` class. I have tried using `never`, `null` and `any` and they all lead to (different) compiler errors that force me to do some weird casts inside of `Maybe's` methods.

You can find a playground of the above code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#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-rkaEYeum7bru7j7vgh5AA).

Here is my thinking. The generic Type `T` on `Maybe` represents the type of the contained value and can be any type. But when `Maybe` is a `None`, it really should be a `never`, since, conceptually, it doesn't have a contained value. In keeping with that, my first thought was to make `None` extend `Maybe<never>` but then the call to `super(null)` triggers a compiler error as `null` is not assignable to type `never`.

The most usable version I came up with is the one where `None` extends `Maybe<any>` but that requires doing a bunch of casting of `(<Some<T>this).value` inside of `Maybe`s methods (not shown in above code) and I don't like that. Ideally, I'd want to find an implementation that doesn't require the use of `any` and casts all over the place. Any help moving towards that will be appreciated.

Comment: Ehh, there really is no value you can assign to `never`, so you could write `super(null!)` and do the one type assertion there and move on.  Or you could refactor so that the base class doesn't pretend to do things it can't do (like hold onto a `never` value), like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBeGgw).  Not sure what you want to do here or see as an answer.

Comment: @jcalz thanks for the quick feedback. It never occured to me to do the `!` type assertion right in the `super(null)` call. But in reality, refactoring the class like you suggest is probably the way to go. So if you want to write an answer I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal change to your code necessary to get it working would probably be this:

```
class None extends Maybe<never> {
    constructor() { super(null!); }
}
```

That is, we are saying that `None` is a `Maybe<never>`, where [the `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) is the [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) with no values.  This is reasonable from a type system standpoint: the "right" type would be something like `forall T. Maybe<T>`, but since TypeScript doesn't have "generic values" like [microsoft/TypeScript#17574](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17574) there's no way to express such a type directly.  Since it looks like `Maybe<T>` should be [covariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)) in `T`, then you could rephrase `forall T. Maybe<T>` as `Maybe<forall T. T>`, which would be equivalent to `Maybe<never>` as the intersection of all types in TypeScript is `never`.

But in order to *construct* a `Maybe<never>` with your code you need to supply a value of type `never` to the super constructor.  This, of course, can't happen.  You're passing `null`, which is not a `never`.  We can use the [non-null assertion operator (postfix `!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) to downcast `null` to `never` (the type of `null!` is `NonNullable<null>` which is `never`).  This is technically a lie, but it's a fairly harmless one, especially if you never try to observe the value later.

---

If you want to be type safe everywhere then I think you'd need to refactor your base class so that it doesn't pretend to do things it can't do.  A `Maybe<T>` might not have a `value` so `value` probably shouldn't be required in the base class.  It could be [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties):

```
abstract class Maybe<T> {
    constructor(public value?: T) { } // <-- optional

    unwrap(): T {
        if (this.isSome()) return this.value; // reverse check
        throw new Error('called unwrap() on None');
    }

    unwrapOr(defaultValue: T): T {
        return this.isSome() ? this.value : defaultValue; // reverse check
    }
}

class Some<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    declare value: T // <-- narrow from optional to required
    constructor(value: T) { super(value); }
}

class None extends Maybe<never> {
    constructor() { super(); } // <-- don't need an argument now
}
```

And then you can [`declare` the property in the subclass](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) to be required (and I have to make it `public` since `private` doesn't let subclasses look at things and even `protected` gets iffy with those type guard functions you have).  Note that I switched your checks from `isNone()` to `isSome()`... the `Maybe<T>` class is not known to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `Some<T> | None`, so you can't use a false result of `isNone()` to conclude that `this.value` is present.  Instead you should use a true result of `isSome()`.

---

Finally, you could just move all the `Some`/`None` specific functionality out of `Maybe`, and then stop worrying about trying to force the base class to behave like both subclasses.  Inheritance-based polymorphism tends to prefer subclasses to override methods instead of having a superclass method that checks for `instanceof`.  This is similar to having `Maybe` just be an `interface`, with the exception of any truly polymorphic methods that don't need to check for the current class:

```
abstract class Maybe<T> {
    abstract isSome(): this is Some<T>;
    abstract isNone(): this is None;
    abstract and<U>(other: Maybe<U>): Maybe<U>;
    abstract unwrapOr(defaultValue: T): T;
}

class Some<T> extends Maybe<T> {
    private value: T
    constructor(value: T) { super(); this.value = value; }
    isSome(): this is Some<T> { return true; }
    isNone(): this is None { return false; }
    and<U>(other: Maybe<U>) {
        return other;
    }
    unwrap() { return this.value }
    unwrapOr(defaultValue: T) { return this.value }
}

class None extends Maybe<never> {
    isSome<T>(): this is Some<T> { return false }
    isNone(): this is None { return true }
    and<U>(other: Maybe<U>) {
        return this;
    }
    unwrapOr<T>(defaultValue: T) { return defaultValue }
}
```

Here, there's nothing in `Maybe` except for abstract methods.  If you can come up with something that doesn't need to check if `this.isSome()` or `this.isNone()` then it can go in the base class.  The only noteworthy thing here is that some of the subclassing for `Maybe<never>` involves turning non-generic methods (`isSome` and `unwrapOr`) into generic methods.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.5.4#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5YECCUoQE4BcBLAe2CQG8BYAKBqXqRACMp9cF8l4AbEbJALIgAnkwgAeACoA+CnQYL4pVrgCu8fMVwAKGLkIA3EPmRHuqiAC4kkgJQUkAXxryF9QlADKxSNtvX8AAsPJBDvSClZKmo3WKRcCHxVXDIgkMJgVhBgRGIAMyRwiABuVzdnWhi4jwA5Ugg-AOCoUJa69DkquIYEpJSkAEI0qAA6DyK-Uq7yl2mFbIATcQBVaW1iILxrIVEJVf9BETEVqLLu3uTU5rGodob7AH4kdAB3JDu-JGsNwLwp7oqZwYqmAL3YMEaNk63QUhAK2mGNw+tnsQVwxDeryQAFFcOidAByeAgbjcCALJAgsEgCH2UjveoE2z-GH0C79RFmCws2KAubA0HglA6BYQPIgVTcfAANRJFmsdgV0NZ8USlyQiNq9U+T1F4slMrlyCaHhGXJKQPoFQUfMUvH4RUiSAgAA8TMAFi0dscZMrYkpMmx1JodOaFfZyEgoKoYHhtObmU4yraGDw+G16s63RAPV6jhJ0AY8Kd+fQAypg1pPpHo7GdMBJdwBonrQwU-Q8iCNCQyHwANYALR8TEIEAA0oQFgB1QLGAASEEkwWAfag2myUBeW0Ou3EKgyAHNpBHLVxlMQySNuMQD+vMlvcCMqULCQBJJDcQh95B9fBkqBMsyyazIoyicFAPjIAAvM8EBvBMBIAMLEL8CTAJwG4PkyPJnoGzyZjBWLIlMZT9kOYAjuOk4zvOi7Lqu2gQZAiYAPQsUgSEoXgOYYfeeAEqRUCDsOo4TtOs74AuS4ZAxwD1Kx7EEu+n7fhqyR-tAAmVHyoCQLACDIMKywemKGTkp0pEsGwHBcPaea7r60TdOWQYaFWMCqEwn7wEg5oPOGDjtm44yQZCwytIUkFOk5Krslc6SBtkuQFEUOE2iB1S3NqBzhSEdx+jCcWDJqXihUBpZJpU3SLCc6ybLg2z5icBzensJYqqqfTxaMWroDqsFvMiXxID8fynkFCjPjSkKSAV3RwkgCLXCFvgop16qckaaVxGiGIDTieJVkSJJkhSU20iNZB3Nh40ZbE53CtoeoSlKsrmFYNgHLNMWskVJUTI8GrXOaw3PQab3crd0xBWmDpRb6rrup6O4+u1cSimmCS+UaCqni5ahuaGOOfQ4tZxgmxSVelVWpnZDIdIjObI614iFsWc2pmBBMhtWUYxnGLbATTHZdkQ9JkSJVHibR0krmumHbiz+7AEeJ4VeWF4QFeN53pueBPoKNKPUpH5fj+6n-oBOEw2BUaQUghFwZFvicahPGMHxuA3dMLn4R0juDdlJHTBLFGidRElSfRa5MRACkcchbvoR7ete4Jwlh1LNGSXRMlrnJ6DxybKnmwQluzDp4DQHAiBIAASmKHBaAVzAqDZsP2ajHP0K31kaK0AMmi0YTw9I2091Z7D9719xDxFdzj4wk82TVqx1ahjW7vsm-HKsi+91PnAPSKjfg8Tio2Nbd22emzsSAj2a5ij99o7EeiGMYpjn3jXOVkT70BRrPzHQiZNrvQdtjd6lNWyxBWrPIG6QWiOkcutDkagShU0ysiOeeVMyRiKuKbgOBoGnlXmsUaDVn7NW7m4IqFDF4wLcOdXmf1gZGkwfdQ2MBHpg1eufCMqDupmnYYwmGdN8qMyfizNmuBX7BVKhEGQYVmgRWQVEQRSBCE4A4fI7BCDh4Zg6PgtUaCLA6PmB6WqFCd5tTVh1VhHgGGnmPpEJ6p8+EAJJsYrqSBeGGnAaI6+nYchi17EJcilExLZyjnnXWD4bF7jYIeY8NCNaXmvLeBWj5j7aGLmbNSZdNIoivsLXCrA7aQAgViBCiduLJyyd7UCeEC7QX2sRa+odIkRxltHRikEi61LQrxVOWl5jhMllEyOuc5baBaUXZS+Tfzl2oI4IAA)

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks for the detailed answer. One (small) "problem" that I've run into while playing with these options is that the compiler can't infer the type of a function that can return both a `Some<T>` and None as being a `Maybe<T>`. Instead it infers the return type as `Some<T> | None`. Which screws up further method chaining. I wonder if there would be a way to get the compiler to recognize that union as being equivalent to `Maybe<T>`. I have added an `andThen` method to your [playground](https://tsplay.dev/wX2Xkm) to illustrate what I mean.

Comment: Obviously, an easy solution is to just explicitly return `Maybe<T>` from that function. But I'm curious if there would be a way for the compiler to not need that.

Comment: Just thinking about types, the refactored version, with the abstract class basically being an interface, looks to be the "cleanest". But then, you might as well use an interface.

An alternative to that would be to have the abstract class implement the `None` variant of all those methods (as it does not require access to the `value`) and then just have `Some` override them. The `None` class would be empty and only extend `Maybe`. You'd save a little bit on code. Not sure I like it though.

Comment: To your first point, `Maybe<T>` is wider than `Some<T> | None` because there may be other subtypes of `Maybe<T>` which are neither `Some<T>` nor `None` (Abstract superclasses are not merely unions of "known" subclasses; this is why I mentioned that checking `this.isNone() === false` does not imply that `this.isSome() === true`.  It's possible for there to be some other type conforming to `Maybe<T>` which is neither.  If you care about `Maybe<T>` you should widen your types manually via annotation, as you mentioned.